# Restart a windows service - "restart the service" didn't help me

Tags: windows, service, windows-service

I have a windows service which crashes sometimes. I have to restart once it happens. So I set "restart the service" on the tab titled "recovery" for first failure, second failure and subsequent failures. But it didn't help me, sometimes I found it stopped.

Why is this happening and how I make it restart each time it crashes no matter what?

Comment: Is there a log file for this service, which you could check?

Comment: @TobiasZander, nothing which would help in this log.